# Creating a shell script to clone multiple git repositories and checkout a particular tag

Tags: git, bash

I'm in need of a shell script which can read a file containing git repository URLs and the desired tag, clone the repository from the url & checkout the listed tag.

Example structure:

http://urlofgitrepohere/project.git:tag-number1

http://urlofgitrepohere/project.git:tag-number2

etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: If this is something you're doing over and over and over again, as the repos update, then it's pretty much the use case for submodules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line; do
  proto=$(echo $line | cut -f 1 -d :)
  url=$(echo $line | cut -f 2 -d :)
  url="${proto}:${url}"
  tag=$(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d :)
  repo=$(echo $url | cut -f 4 -d /)
  git clone $url && git --git-dir=$repo/.git checkout $tag
done < $1
```

Comment: This script was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you